Same table check one column value and check existing in another column
I have a table, I want to write a T-SQL query that selects Parent id value from the table and then checks this value within the Design ID column.
My table is like this - table name is Tbl_project:

I need to verify if any Parent IDs are missing from the Design ID column. In this scenario, Parent ID = 50 is not present in the Design ID column, so I want to populate only that values value
I tried with a sub query, but I'm not getting expected result

Even if it's a small table, please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question. "I tried with sub query, but not getting expected result" you forgot to include that attempt, and explain why it didn't work. You also don't include your expected results here.

What did you try and what didn't work as expected?  As an aside... If the goal is to maintain referential integrity, a foreign key back to the same table would accomplish that actively as records are inserted/updated.

@ThomA noted, expected result here is i want to show Parant ID : 50 , because that value is not existing in the Design ID column

Is there a reason you don't have this as an FK constraint? That way it wouln'd enter a bad state in the first place...

Try something like select parentid from yourtable t where not exists(select 1 from yourtable t2 where t2.designid = t.parentid)

This is the query i tried, "select p1.parant_id from Tbl_project p1  where p1.parant_id not in
(select p2.design ID from project p2)

@user3262364, a NOT IN query will also work as expected, as long as no designid values are NULL.

You could also try select ParantID from tbl_project group by ParantID having count (case when ParantID = DesignID then 1 end) = 0; to query the table only once. I don't know if it's faster because it requires grouping. Might depend on indices.

Another option is to use a subquery in the where clause
select p.parantid 
from   tbl_project p 
where not exists (select 1 from tbl_project p2 where p2.designid = p.parantid);

See this dbFiddle

You can use EXCEPT to return these values:
select Parent_ID from the_table
except
select Design_ID from the_table

